# Getting coordinate of elements on my laptop screen

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am making a fun python program to automate couple clicks for me. I want to use pyAutoGui library provided by python to make this program. I am struggled to find the coordinates of elements that I want to click. Are there any ways that I can find coordinates of my elements?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pyautogui.mouseInfo()`.

MouseInfo is an application to display the XY position and RGB color information of the pixel currently under the mouse. Works on Python 2 and 3. This is useful for GUI automation planning.

The full documentation is at https://mouseinfo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I tried to use it, but when I hovered the mouse over a checkbox, the "XY Position" field did not display anything. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you open the application? If yes, there is a button with the text "Copy XY (F2)". If you press this button the application will copy the X and Y position on your clipboard with a 3 second delay. The 3 second delay will give you time to go too the checkbox. After the 3 seconds, you can past (CTRL + V) the coordinates in your editor of choice.

Answer (score 1):

[Point Position](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/pointpos.html) (for Windows) is a simple tool that lets you pick the coordinates for any point on your screen (using X,Y axis). Simply point one of the four corner arrows at the spot on your screen that you want to define and click the button to display the X/Y coordinates.